# How do you troubleshoot all Apache threads becoming occupied and idle?

Tags: performance, apache, drupal, drupal-6, apache2

I have a Drupal 6 site that is frequently (about once a day) going down. The hosting provider is reporting that something in our site code is occupying all Apache threads but keeping them idle, making the server run out of threads to respond to new requests. A simple restart of Apache frees the threads and fixes the issue, though it reoccurs within a few hours or a day.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue and have never come across PHP code doing this. Is there some kind of Apache settings change I can make to capture more information about what might be keeping a thread occupied but idle? What typical PHP routines can cause this behavior? I looked for code that connects to external resources, but didn't see any issues there.

Any hints for what to look at, capture more information, or PHP code that can cause this would be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

With Drupal6 you could have the [poormanscron](http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron) module running sometimes, or even the classical cron (from crontab wget or whatever).
Then you could get one heavy cron operation putting your database under heavy stuff. Then if your database reponse time is becoming very slow every http request will become very slow (as for example sessions are in the database, and several hundreds queries are required for a drupal page). having all reqests slowing down may put all the avàilable php process in a 'occupied state'.

Restarting apache all current process are stoped. If you run the cron via wget and not via drush cron tasks are a nice thing to check (running cron via drush would make it run via php-cli' restarting apache would not kill the cron). You can try a module like [elysia cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to get more details on cron tasks and maybe isolate the long ones (you have a report on tasks duration).

This effect (one request hurting bad the database, all requests slowing down, no more process available) could also be done by one bad piece of code coming from any of your installed modules. This would be harder to detect.

So I would ensure slow queries are tracked on MySQL (see my.cnf otinons), then analyse theses requests with tolls like [mysqsla](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlsla). The problem is that sometimes one query  is so big that all query becames slow. Se use time of crash te detect the first ones. Use also tho MySQL option to track queries not using indexes.

Another way to get all apache process stalled on php operation with drupal is having a **lock** problem. Drupal is using is [own lock implementation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!lock.inc/6) with MySQL. You could maybe add some **watchdog** (drupal internal debug messages) calls on theses files to try to detect locks problems.

Then you could also have sonme **external http requests calls** made by drupal. Calling external websites like facebook, google, some tiny url tools, or drupal.org module update things (which always try to find all modules, even the one you write). If the distant website is down or filtering your traffic you'll have problems (but the apache restart would not help you, so it may not be that).

Comment: Thanks! Cron is run via drush. Great point about a restart not impacting that, so it's not cron. We aren't using Poormanscron. And I'm not seeing high MySQL load when this happens. How would the Apache restart not help with external HTTP requests?

Comment: well if you have all your process stuck on external requests they miss a timeout setting. now if they sometimes timeout -- which should happen -- new process are having same external communication problems. Restarting apache would not make new process having better external connections just beecause you've killed old connections... or maybe it does because of a mx-number-of connection reached by your websuti on this exte,rnal resource...